# How to add new object to an array of objects in Mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have been trying to add the following data to the **"answers"** array in the database using postman 'PUT' operation , but it returns **null** and I can't seem to find why the data is not added to the database?

This is the data that needs to be added/updated.

```
{
  "author": "Austin Poulson",
  "timeStamp": "20 August, 2016",
  "detailedanswer1": "ReactJS is a framework for building an hierarchy of UI components. Each component has state and props. Data flows from the top to low-level components via props. The state is updated in the top-level component using event handlers.React native uses React framework for building components for mobile apps. React native provides a basic set of components for both iOS and Android platforms. Some of the components in React Native are Navigator, TabBar, Text, TextInput, View, ScrollView. These components use native iOS UIKit and Android UI components internally. React native also allows NativeModules where code written in ObjectiveC for iOS and Java for Android can be used within JavaScript.Note: React Native as a framework allows for development of mobile apps in similar syntax to HTML and CSS. React Native components effectively replace HTML in native development.",
  "ans1comments": [
    {
      "comment": "",
      "comment_author": ""
    },
    {
      "comment": "",
      "comment_author": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the what is shown in the console after making the API call

```
{
    "newAns": {
        "acknowledged": true,
        "modifiedCount": 2,
        "upsertedId": null,
        "upsertedCount": 0,
        "matchedCount": 2
    }
}
```

The GET Method works flawlessly fetching data but PUT doesn't work.

Here is the schema of data in the database

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "question": {
      "heading": "",
      "description": "",
      "tags": [],
      "author": "",
      "timeStamp": "",
      "quecomments": [
        {
          "comment": "",
          "comment_author": ""
        },
        {
          "comment": "",
          "comment_author": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    "answers": [
      {
        "author": "",
        "timeStamp": "",
        "detailedanswer1": "",
        "ans1comments": [
          {
            "comment": "",
            "comment_author": ""
          },
          {
            "comment": "",
            "comment_author": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "author": "",
        "timeStamp": "",
        "detailedanswer2": "",
        "ans2comments": [
          {
            "comment": "",
            "comment_author": ""
          },
          {
            "comment": "",
            "comment_author": ""
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

Below is the code

```
export async function AddAnswer(id, answers) {
    return await client
        .db("StackOvercloned")
        .collection("stackdata")
        .updateMany({ id: id }, { $push: { answers: answers } });
}
```

```
router.put("/:id", async function (request, response) {
    const { id } = request.params;
    const answers = request.body;
    const newAns = await AddAnswer(id, answers);
    console.log(newAns);
    newAns ?
        response.send({ newAns })
        : response.send(404).send({ msg: "Error occured " })
});
```

Comment: is the id unique?

Comment: Which funtion call returns "null"? All your code snippetes show that the funtions work as expected.

Comment: There are a few questions here. If you use `updateMany` I assume `id` is not unique? Also do you push a single answer, or many answers? Because if it's the latter, you need to use `$each` as well.

Comment: Yes, I have provided unique id to every object . Also the AddAnswer function does not add the above data to the "answers" array. All I see is null at the end of the answers array. I will be pushing single answer at a time.

Comment: What is the content of `request.body`? It really depends on how you're parsing the payload...

Comment: I believe it is what I add under the body in Postman. It is the first code snippet above that I have mentioned.